# Pass string parameters to an onclick() function and display it in a modal

Tags: javascript, php

I have indexed binary files(pdfs, docs and spreadsheets). How can I add an onclick() function that takes in 3 string parameters (name, details and location) and displays them on a modal preserving the documents format i.e for the spreadsheet, show the table and for the docs and pdfs, show indentation and formating. If I use htmlentities, I get a syntax error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKagM.png) but it points here [error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCqh9.png).

What could be causing the error?

```
<label  class="btn btn-info btn-sm openBtn" data-toggle="modal" onclick={searchDetails('<?php echo 
                                                            $r['_source']['file']['filename']; ?>',
                                                            "<?php echo htmlentities($r['_source']['content']);?>",
                                                            '<?php echo addslashes($r['_source']['path']['real']); ?>',                                                             
                                        )}> Details </label >
.
.
.

function searchDetails(filename, content, link){
    var docUrl= "file://" + "///" + link.substring(2);
    var search_id = $(this).attr("$r['_source']['content']");
    console.log("Link" + link);
    console.log("URL" + (docUrl));
    document.getElementById("doc_header").innerHTML = filename;
    document.getElementById("doc_content").innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById("doc_link").innerHTML = docUrl;
    document.getElementById("doc_link").setAttribute("href",link);
    document.getElementById("doc_link").setAttribute("target","_blank");
    $('#myModal').modal("show");    
}
```

Comment: Try to use `onclick=""` with quotes not `{` . Ex: `onclick="searchDetails('one',\"two\", 3)"` .  It's not ok to pass so much data like that rom an attribute. I recommend to at least encode it first.

Comment: I am using the function to dynamically load the content of the modal. How do I encode it?